# Grouping time series as hierarchial data

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I am trying to create a hierarchial time series based on some sample data. What I want to do is

first column becomes the total of quarters, that is total for the year,

that is

```
level 0 : total for the year
level 1: Quarter 1 = (sum of Jan, feb, march, april), etc
level 2 : available data for months Jan to Dec
```

so far I have achieved this:

```
library(forecast)
library(hts)

htsqpass.ts <- ts(rnorm(100), start=2015, frequency=12)

quar<-rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), each = 12)
mth<-rep(c("April","August","December","February","January","July","June","March","May","November","September","October"), each=4)

rownames(mth) <- c("Quarter", "Month")
x <- gts(abc, groups = gc)
x
```

Is there an easier way to construct the timeseries

Comment: What is `gc`? Use `month.name`.

Comment: yes, sorry, I was looking into other codes as well

Comment: Still not working, always check question code in a fresh R session.

Comment: Hey jay.sf, thats why I asked the question.